# How to access an attribute from a JSON line saved in a position from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This may be a very simple question but I really can't seem to make it work.

I have several JSON lines and a `notes` array. 
Using `notes.push(JSONline)` I am saving one JSON line per array position, I assume, so in the following manner:

```
//notes[1]
{"id":"26","valuee":"20","datee":"2016-04-05T15:15:45.184+0100","id2":51}
//notes[2]
{"id":"27","valuee":"134","datee":"2016-04-05T15:15:47.238+0100","id2":53}
//notes[3]
{"id":"26","valuee":"20","datee":"2016-04-05T15:15:45.184+0100","id2":52}
```

Here is my problem: I want to print one specific attribute, for example id from one specific JSON line in the array. How can I do this?

When I do `console.log(notes)` it prints all the JSON lines just as expected. But if I do `console.log(notes[1])` it prints the first character of the JSON line in that position, not the whole line.
Similarly `console.log(notes[1].id)` does not print the id from the first JSON line, in fact it prints 'undefined'.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Edit question, add all your code, how do you push elements

Comment: Try using `notes = JSON.parse(notes)` then try printing using index.

Comment: How is jSONline generated?

Comment: There must be some parsing error only, since everything looks fine as per inputs shown here, parse it with `JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that JSON is the string representation of a JS object. JS strings have similar index accessor methods to arrays which is why you can write `console.log(notes[0])` and get back the first letter.

JavaScript *doesn't* allow you to access the string using object notation, however, so `console.log(notes[0].id)` will not work and the reason you get `undefined`.

To access the data in the string using this method you need to **parse** the string to an object first.

```
var notes = ['{"id":"26","valuee":"20","datee":"2016-04-05T15:15:45.184+0100","id2":51}'];
var note0 = JSON.parse(notes[0]);
var id = note0.id;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6d4qey6L/)

This leaves the question of why you have an array of JSON strings. While it's not weird or unusual, it might not be the most optimum solution. Instead you could build an array of objects and then stringify the whole data structure to keep it manageable.

```
var obj0 = {
  "id": "26",
  "valuee": "20",
  "datee": "2016-04-05T15:15:45.184+0100",
  id2: 51
};

var obj1 = {
  "id": "27",
  "valuee": "134",
  "datee": "2016-04-05T15:15:47.238+0100",
  "id2": 53
}

var arr = [obj0, obj1];
var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
    "id": "26",
    "valuee": "20",
    "datee": "2016-04-05T15:15:45.184+0100",
    "id2": 51
  },
  {
    "id": "27",
    "valuee": "134",
    "datee": "2016-04-05T15:15:47.238+0100",
    "id2": 53
  }
]
```

You can then parse the JSON back to an array and access it like before:

```
var notes = JSON.parse(json);
notes[0].id // 26
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you parse all the json when you are pushing to notes, like:

```
notes.push(JSON.parse(JSONLine))
```

If you are somehow attached to having json strings in an array instead of objects, which I wouldn't recommend, you could always just parse once you have the jsonLine id

```
JSON.parse(notes[id]).id
```

Basically, you want to use JSON.parse for either solution and I'd strongly recommend converting them to objects once at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you have `{"id": "value"...` as a string in your key value pairs. `"id"` is a string so you can't reference it like a property. 1. use

```
var notes = JSON.parse(notes);
```

as mentioned in the comments by The alpha 
 or remove the quotes try

```
{id:"26", ...}
```

that's why `notes[i].id` is returning undefined

Comment: Quoting keys is proper JSON syntax. Quoting ˙id˙ or not, doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Also the asker expects `notes` to be an array, here it becomes the object parsed from a JSON string.